# Finding department having maximum number of employee

Tags: sql

I have a table employee

```
id name  dept
1  bucky shp
2  name  shp
3  other mrk
```

How can i get the name of the department(s)  having maximum number of employees ? ..

I need result

```
dept
--------
shp
```

Comment: Where is the number of employee stored for each department? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: it is an employee table .. with employee id name . and department employee is working ..

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cnt,deptno FROM (
SELECT rank() OVER (ORDER BY cnt desc) AS rnk,cnt,deptno from
(SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, DEPTNO FROM EMP
GROUP BY deptno))
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Rather than just pasting the answer please explain why you are suggesting this solution so that the user learns how to do this on their own.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server and each record representing an employee. So you can use window function to get the result

```
WITH C AS (
    SELECT  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY dept) Rnk
            ,name
            ,dept
    FROM table
)
SELECT TOP 1 dept FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(Rnk) cnt, dept FROM C GROUP BY dept) t
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

With common table expressions, count the number of rows per department, then find the biggest count, then use that to select the biggest department.

```
WITH depts(dept, size) AS (
  SELECT dept, COUNT(*) FROM employee GROUP BY dept
), biggest(size) AS (
  SELECT MAX(size) FROM depts
)
SELECT dept FROM depts, biggest WHERE depts.size = biggest.size
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on one of the answer, Let me try to explain step by step

First of all we need to get the employee count department wise. So the firstly innermost query will run

```
select count(*) cnt, deptno from scott.emp group by deptno
```

This will give result as

[image]

Now out of this we have to get the one which is having max. employee i.e. department 30.

Also please note there are chances that 2 departments have same number of employees

The second level of query is

```
select rank() over (order by cnt desc) as rnk,cnt,deptno from
(
   select count(*) cnt, deptno from scott.emp group by deptno
)
```

Now we have assigned ranking to each department

[image]

Now to select rank 1 out of it. we have a simplest outer query

```
select * from 
(
  select rank() over (order by cnt desc) as rnk,cnt,deptno from
   (
      select count(*) cnt, deptno from scott.emp group by deptno
   )
)
 where rnk=1
```

So we have the final result where we got the department which has the maximum employees. If we want the minimum one we have to include the department table as there are chances there is a department which has no employees which will not get listed in this table

You can ignore the **scott** in scott.emp as that is the table owner.

The above SQL can be practised at [Practise SQL online](https://livesql.oracle.com)